# IOS 11.3 PWA Add to Home Screen

Tags: ios, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

With IOS 11.3 now supporting service workers and PWA's will the same 'add to home screen' functionality like android be available?

I know you can do this manually via `share > add to home screen` but I wonder if this will be automatic like Android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this thorough article](https://medium.com/@firt/progressive-web-apps-on-ios-are-here-d00430dee3a7), the manual tapping of add to home screen is required at least right now.

Comment: And this is only available if you use Safari, not Chrome on iOS, right? Or is there a way to do it in Chrome on iOS?